# Can I make the content heights inside these cards level/equal without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a bootstrap row with three col-md-3's, and inside of each I have my own `cards`, with four children elements.

What I am trying to do is line up all of these elements inside the card EXACTLY the same as the other cards, almost as if a ruler had been held up to them.

I have tried this combination of display: flex with flex: 1 and flex: 2 on the child elements, but I cannot seem to get this to work where all the heights are equal across all elements.

I have tried using Javascript to calculate the tallest height of each element and set the others accordingly, which works, but I was wondering if there's a way to do this without Javascript.

```css
.my-card {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.my-card > p {
  flex: 2;
}
.my-card > h3 {
  flex: 1;
}
.img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 72px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="my-card">
          <h2>01</h2>
          <h3>Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias autem cumque ducimus ipsam minus, molestias nemo nobis odio suscipit voluptatem?</p>
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="my-card">
          <h2>02</h2>
          <h3>Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias autem cumque ducimus ipsam minus, molestias nemo nobis odio suscipit voluptatem?</p>
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="my-card">
          <h2>03</h2>
          <h3>Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, molestias?</h3>
          <p>Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A consectetur consequuntur doloremque, minus molestiae nam placeat, praesentium, repellat repellendus reprehenderit vero voluptas. Alias dolorum ducimus maxime nisi ullam. Consectetur, expedita. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias autem cumque ducimus ipsam minus, molestias nemo nobis odio suscipit voluptatem?</p>
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems more like a `grid` layout is needed

Answer (score 1):

You can try with css grid, pls. take a look at snippet below:

```css
.my-card{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 3fr auto;
  align-items: start;
}
.img{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h2{
  font-size: 72px;
}
h3{
  font-size: 30px;
}
p{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="my-card">
                    <h2>01</h2>
                    <h3>Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias autem cumque ducimus ipsam minus, molestias nemo nobis odio suscipit voluptatem?</p>
                    <div class="img"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="my-card">
                    <h2>02</h2>
                    <h3>Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias autem cumque ducimus ipsam minus, molestias nemo nobis odio suscipit voluptatem?</p>
                    <div class="img"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="my-card">
                    <h2>03</h2>
                    <h3>Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, molestias?</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A consectetur consequuntur doloremque, minus molestiae nam placeat, praesentium, repellat repellendus reprehenderit vero voluptas. Alias dolorum ducimus maxime nisi ullam. Consectetur, expedita. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias autem cumque ducimus ipsam minus, molestias nemo nobis odio suscipit voluptatem?</p>
                    <div class="img"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```